# Sequencing sounds into a ByteArray seamlessly - flash, as3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, arrays

I'm creating the soundtrack for a video which consists of an intro sound clip, a looping middle one, and an end clip.  I need to write these dynamically to a ByteArray and then combine them with bitmaps to make a video.  It's working, except in the video output I get a tiny delay between the intro sound ending and the loop sound beginning (the audio files do not have any silence, they are seamless) - can anyone advise how I could avoid this?  (_soundIntro, _soundLoop and _soundEnd are the embedded audio files.)

```
var baAudio:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var baAudioIntro:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var baAudioLoop:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var baAudioEnd:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

var totalLength:Number = (_bitmaps.length / FLV_FRAMERATE) * 44000;
var loopLength:Number = totalLength - (_soundIntro.length * 44.1) - (_soundEnd.length * 44.1);

_soundIntro.extract(baAudioIntro, _soundIntro.length * 44.1);
_soundLoop.extract(baAudioLoop, loopLength);
_soundEnd.extract(baAudioEnd, _soundEnd.length * 44.1);

baAudio.writeBytes(baAudioIntro);
baAudio.writeBytes(baAudioLoop);
baAudio.writeBytes(baAudioEnd);
```

Comment: just updated my code - it works but i still have little gaps between each audio section.

Comment: hmm sounds like it could be down to this: http://www.netalive.org/swsu/archives/2007/01/gapless_mp3_loops_in_flash_1.html - waiting on wav files to test it out!

Comment: Flash is not the best language to do those kind of things, it's not powerful enough. You should try Processing or OpenFrameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the answer was that .mp3 encoding outside of flash tends to leave gaps at the beginning and end of audio clips, preventing a seamless loop/transition (http://www.netalive.org/swsu/archives/2007/01/gapless_mp3_loops_in_flash_1.html)
I switched to .wav files, imported to Flash (thus letting Flash handle the encoding) and it fixed the issue.